# find django models referenced more than once (and another complex lookup)

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models:

contact - information about a contact happening to a person
client - information about a person referenced in contact

I need to find clients that have been referenced in contact 3 or more times. To do this, something like this works. Not sure this is the most effective way of doing this but it's one line that does the job without me having to loop over the clients.

```
client.objects.all().annotate(c_count=Count('contacted_client')).filter(c_count__gte=3)
```

Now it gets harder a bit. Contact has a date.

I need to find all clients who have been contacted within 5 or more weeks in time: "find all clients referenced in contact where Max(contact_date)-Min(contact_date) > 5 weeks". I tried to use the same approach but can't figure how to do this.

The logic of figuring this on per-client basis is something like this:

```
min_date = contact.objects.filter(client=self).aggregate(Min('date'))['date__min']
max_date = contact.objects.filter(client=self).aggregate(Max('date'))['date__max']
    if (max_date - min_date).days > 5*7:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

But if I perform this check for many clients, it just gets slow.

Comment: I think it's too hard for ORM and you should use [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/sql/) for the lookup

Comment: I think it's posible to do it, but i would like you to add your models here (those you think are relevant to this query) so i can get a better aproach to your problem. I think i have the answer but i'm not sure about your models relations...